# HMI for small desktop laboratory equipment

Tags: wireless, interface

We are building desktop laboratory equipments and wondering whats the next step for HMI from 40x2 Text display and small switches.

Idea we are contemplating are...

1. bluetooth in device and android or ios phone
2. wifi or other zigbee protocol with webserver and phone
3. touch screen and full LCD

Our idea is to connect equipment to smartphone somehow ( bluetooth/nfc/wifi ) and display whole user interface on phone itself.

Best and Cheapest Idea I have is to connect equipment ( lets say, arduino ) to phone is via NFC ( which is a saparate device wired via a long wire to actual equipment ) to which one should attach their own phone, which enables the app to communicate directly to the device.

what you guys are doing as next step of hmi ?

Comment: Personally I would go route 3. The others sound a bit daft for a piece of desktop equipment.  Like you're using a gimmick for gimmick's sake.

Comment: What do your customers expect?

Comment: You may have to support more than one interface simultaneously.. I can't see customers being overjoyed with a requirement to use an android iOS or windows mobile device because the manufacturer left out the front panel. One issue you'll possubly run into is the synchronization issues related to loosely coupled systems with different clocks, especially if millisecond or better timing is important in your applications ( it becomes more than an HMI when customers want to manipulate data on the mobile device).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I think it's entirely dependent on your application requirements. Data rates, latency, distance, etc... For example, In our truck scale application, the scale talks to a cell modem which connects to centralized servers. The phone app connects to the centralized server. In this manner information can be exchanged between many truck stops while only authenticating once.

If you intend to have many users and hosts, then a centralized architecture allows you to tap in at the backbone for things like upgrades and user management. Can't do that with a bunch of NFC pairs.

Answer (score 0):

We've done 3 inch LCD + resistive touch screen - the cost is something like $5 - and are working on adding on BLE (or Bluetooth Smart as it's called today) to add cellphone control option.

The cellphone control cannot be the only option, because then you'd have to support all the different cellphone platforms (Windows, Android, iOS, and that list is far from complete). And really, do you want to force your users to dig up their cell for every little thing you do or setting you change? At least provide the basic functionality without the cellphone.